# Frameworks File not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, opentok, build-settings

I'm converting my old(32 bit) project to new (64 bit). I'm facing this issue for past one day. Still I'm not able to resolve the issue.  I used RestKit project, FacebookSDK & Opentok frameworks. I added those frameworks into my project directory.

My project target -> BuildSettings

Framework Search paths :

```
$(inherited) 
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers”
```

Header Search paths :

```
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers" 
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Opentok/Headers" 
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/FacebookSDK/Headers"
```

Library Search Paths :

```
<Nothing>
```

User header search paths :

```
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/RestKit-RestKit-c19a500/Build"  
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/FacebookSDK/Headers"  
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Opentok/Headers"
```

For this I'm getting the below error

```
'Opentok/Opentok.h' file not found
```

I changed the above path directory

```
PROJECT_DIR ==> SRCROOT
```

Now I'm getting the below errors

```
'Opentok/Opentok.h' file not found
'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found
```

Comment: check once your embed binaries the frame work added or not

Comment: Yes its added, I'm getting  'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found

Answer (score 0):

seem like you set the wrong path.Roll back the the PROJECT_DIR ==> SRCROOT changes and try to set the Opentok path to where Opentok's DIR locates but not into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove all setings and framework related to opentok and install using cocoapods , then you dont need any matual settings

https://cocoapods.org/?q=Opentok